# League Table - SQL Query/JDBC Issue

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I currently have a very basic app that interacts with a database (Using netbeans and the jdbc) so that you can add teams, players and scores. I now need to be able to display items from each table together in a League Table/Team (With players) Table etc etc.

My question is how do I go about retrieving the information from the tables and how do I display it, I am literally clueless as to how I should go about it. I'm assuming I need to do a Join or Select statement (I'm a complete SQL novice) and then use a loop to select each table entry and display it in a table somehow?

The only current working features I have are adding to the database, IE add a new team add a new player etc, displaying what is in the tables on the form is where I am stumped.

Any tips or help is much appreciated.

The code I am currently using is this; (I still need to implement a score table and adding records to that, I also created the datbase using the GUI and so have no foreign keys set, is there a way to do this WITHIN netbeans as I have no "Create Table" code anywhere.

```
package football.game;
/*import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;*/
import football.game.DBconnection;
import java.sql.*;


/**
 *
 * @author Steffan Caine
 */
public class SportsConnection extends DBconnection {

public SportsConnection(final String dbName)
{
    this.connectDatabase(dbName);
}

public void insertPlayer(final Integer PLAYERNUM,
        final String PLAYERNAME, final String PLAYERPOS, final Integer TEAMNUM)
{
    final String insertStmt = "INSERT INTO APP.PLAYERS (PLAYERNUM, PLAYERNAME, PLAYER_POS, TEAM_ID) VALUES (?,?, ?, ?)";
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(insertStmt);

        pstmt.setInt(1, PLAYERNUM);
        pstmt.setString(2, PLAYERNAME);
        pstmt.setString(3, PLAYERPOS);
        pstmt.setInt(4, TEAMNUM);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception when inserting player record: " + sqle.toString());
    }
}

public void insertTeam(final String NAME, final String MANAGER, final int ID)
{
    final String insertStmt = "INSERT INTO APP.TEAMS (TEAMNAME, MANAGER, TEAM_ID) VALUES (?,?, ?)";
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(insertStmt);

        pstmt.setString(1, NAME);
        pstmt.setString(2, MANAGER);
        pstmt.setInt(3, ID);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception when inserting team record: " + sqle.toString());
    }
}

 public void printAllRecords()
{
    this.setQuery(retrieveQuery);
    this.runQuery();
    ResultSet output = this.getResultSet();
    try
    {
    if (null != output)
    {
        while(output.next())
        {

            String PLAYERNUM = output.getString(1);
            String PLAYERNAME = output.getString(2);

            System.out.println (PLAYERNUM + "\n" + PLAYERNAME + "\n");

        }
    }
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception when printing all students: " + sqle.toString());
    }

}

}
```

The "retrieveQuery" currently returns an error message, any help getting that part to work would be great as printing the records out in a console would add some much needed (If basic) functionality.

I also have classes for each form (AddPlayer/AddTeam/Navigation) but I am not using constructors to populate the database I am instead using Methods located in a Main class, is this a bad way to go about things as I am not using "Objects" as such?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see three tables: PLAYER, TEAM, and LEAGUE.

A TEAM has many PLAYERs; a LEAGUE has many TEAMs.  These should be one-to-many relationships, so you'll have foreign keys.  Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE PLAYER (
    int id not null auto increment,
    first_name varchar(80),
    last_name varchar(80),
    int team_id,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(team_id) references TEAM(id)
);

CREATE TABLE TEAM (
    int id not null auto increment,
    name varchar(80),
    primary key(id)
);
```

So you might have Java classes like this:

```
package model;

public class Player {
    private Integer id,
    private String name;
// ctors, getters, etc.
}

public class Team {
    private Integer id,
    private String name,
    List<Player> players;
// ctors, getters, etc.
}
```

You'll have a persistence layer that will have all your SQL in it:

```
package persistence;

public interface PlayerDao {
    Player find(Integer id);
    List<Player> find();
    Integer save(Player p);
    void update(Player p);
    void delete(Player p);
}
```

Here's a sample implementation for PlayerDao:

```
package persistence; 

public class PlayerDaoImpl implements PlayerDao {
    private static final String SELECT_ALL = "SELECT id, name FROM PLAYER ";
    private static final String SELECT_BY_ID = SELECT_ALL + "WHERE id = ?";

    private Connection connection;

    public PlayerDaoImpl(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public Player find(Integer id) {
        Player p = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_BY_ID);
            ps.setInteger(1, id);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Integer pid = rs.getInteger("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                p = new Player(id, name);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            DatabaseUtils.close(rs);
            DatabaseUtils.close(ps);
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

Printing records in consoles or user interfaces would indeed be useful, but that should be done by different classes in different packages.  Have a view tier that handles that stuff.  Classes should do one thing well.  You should think about layering your applications appropriately.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I am not an experienced programmer and so some of your answer made little sense to me, I've expanded on my question and if you could try helping out some more I'd be grateful.

Comment: Helping you out some more?  Did you see the code that I wrote for you?  Am I supposed to write the entire app?  I'm a volunteer, not a paid consultant.  You're new; put in some effort to learn.

Comment: My problem with understanding your answer comes from the fact you are using classes to populate the database and in my original app I am just using methods in a class.

Here you have:
'package persistence;

public interface PlayerDao {
    Player find(Integer id);
    List<Player> find();
    Integer save(Player p);
    void update(Player p);
    void delete(Player p);
}'

Are these just methods I'd write or are these existing commands or? 

I didn't mean to sound ungrateful, I just am struggling with understanding what you have wrote as it is different to what I've learn't previously.

Comment: Concentrate on the method, not the class that owns it.  Yes, you'd write all these.  Nobody gives them to you.